# Continuous optimization

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, economics

I'm interested in the solution to the following problem:

I have initial capital $C$ which I can invest into $M$ classes of
resources, each unit of a class $m_i$ matures at time $t_i$, has a
return of $r_i$ and a cost $c_i$. After the asset matures it the proceeds can be re-invested. What is the optimal strategy to
invest $C$ in terms of profit at time $t$ and for $t\rightarrow\infty$?

I am interested in both cases where $m_i$ is in the non-negative reals and the case when $m_i$ is a member of the non-negative integers.

What is the field that studies this type of continual optimization problem?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what is $\mathbb{R}^{*}$?

Comment: Also to answer your question as to what is the field that studies this topic, I'm not sure what kind of answer you are are looking for, but these types of problems are routinely handled in mathematical programming, operations research, financial mathematics, etc. 

Comment: Gilead: with the way things are on these sorts of problems, I suppose it means "the set of positive reals."

Comment: @J. Mangaldan: I think that makes sense. I'm more used to $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ for positive reals.

Comment: Non-negative reals (I allow zero investment in a particular class)

Comment: I should clarify: The challenge in the problem is re-investment: After an asset matures the proceeds may be used to buy more assets of any class. I will edit the post to clarify.

Comment: Also I know about operations research but from what I know of OR it deals with "one-shot" type problems. I'm asking if there is some more specific sub-field that deals with multiple decisions. Maybe I will look at iterated one-player games.

Comment: (1) The thing is, in the second case (where $m_i$ are nonnegative integers), I can't see how you would get a continuous optimization problem. Unless you have another definition of continuous. (2) If reinvestment is allowed, then the problem more difficult, because now each $m_{i}$ is no longer a single value, since decisions can change over time. It sounds like what you might want to look into the "continuous-time scheduling" literature. Mind you, you'll still end up with a discrete optimization problem. (3) Try asking this question at http://www.or-exchange.com. 

Comment: I meant continuous as "repeated" or "iterated". I will ask at or-exchange. I didn't realize that existed.

Comment: http://www.or-exchange.com/questions/632/iterated-investment

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would develop the formulation (conceptually).

- Investment costs, $Q$:
  $$Q = \sum_{i} m_{i} c_{i}$$
- Investment returns for $i$ at time $t$: we know that the return for $i$ is $m_{i} r_{i}$ if $t \geq t_{i}$, otherwise it is 0.  To model this `if` logical condition:
  $$ R = \sum_{i} \delta_{i} m_{i} r_{i} $$
  $$ \delta_{i} = 1, \text{ if } t \geq t_{i} $$
  $$ \delta_{i} = 0, \text{ if } t < t_{i} $$
  where $R$ = overall returns. In this case, $t$ and $t_{i}$ are parameters, therefore $\delta_{i}$ are parameters too, not binary variables. They can be pre-calculated for a specified $t$.

---

In summary, your problem can be represented as follows:

$$ \max_{m_{i}} (R - Q)$$
s.t. 
$$ Q = \sum_{i} m_{i} c_{i}$$
$$ R = \sum_{i} \delta_{i} m_{i} r_{i}$$
$$ Q \leq C $$
$$ m_{i} \geq 0\quad \forall i$$

where $C, c_{i}, r_{i}, \delta_{i}, t, t_{i}$ are parameters.

So, if $m_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$, this would be a linear program. If $m_{i} \in \mathbb{N}$, this becomes a mixed-integer linear program. (Note: for tractability in the integer case, you may need to specify a reasonably small upper-bound for $m_{i}$ or use partial integer variables)

For $t \rightarrow \infty$ (i.e. all the investments have reached maturity), simply set all $\delta_{i} = 1$.

Comment: I clarified in the post that re-investments of profits are permitted. This was clear original but it is this that posed the essential difficulty for me.

Comment: This answer was valid under the assumption of no reinvestment. With reinvestment, a different approach is needed.

Comment: Yes, obviously. Do you want the reputation points and me to re-post the edited question?

Comment: No, it's okay, don't worry about it. I'm interested to see what the people at OR-Exchange come up with -- the problem is not as easy as it looks. 

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $c_i$  is the cost for investment per unit till maturity. Then for a particular class $m_i$, the gain per unit investment per time is $$\frac{(1+r_i)-c_i}{t_i}$$

Consequently, minimize the quantity over all $i$ and invest all your money there.

Comment: I'm thinking while this maximizes overall profit, but it doesn't account for the fact that a given time $t$, not all investments have reached maturity, hence the payout at time $t$ is not necessarily optimal. What do you think?

Comment: Yes I agree with the problem raised by Gilead. Profits are only realized at discrete time intervals.

Comment: Yes, but it won't matter as $t\rightarrow\infty$. That condition effectively means you don't know when the system will end, and you keep repeating your investments for ever.

Comment: Also if the $t\rightarrow\infty$ condition is removed, the solution hardly changes - then at each repeat you will keep investing your money at the class given by the same formula. Only you need to be careful that at each repeat of the investment, you must not consider the classes which takes longer to mature than the time you have remaining.

Comment: I think the latter condition makes the greedy approach non-optimal. Presumably there is some other strategy that may "fit" better into the timeline so that less time goes "unused" and consequently yield a higher total return (depending of the specific rates of return.

I'm not sure if it is obvious that there exists a $T$ such that one strategy will dominate all others for all $t > T$.